# $_FILES superglobal causes 500 Server Error

Tags: php, file, http, file-upload

**EDIT:** Error = Warning: Undefined array key "file_upload"

Trying to setup file attachments for my site, but can't get past this...

**HTML Form**

```
<form action="file_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file_upload">
   <button type="submit" name="file_submit">UPLOAD</button>
</form>
```

**PHP Function**

```
<?php
    $file = $_FILES['file_upload'];
    print_r($file);
```

**Error**

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Version: HTTP/2
Transferred: 1.18 kB (0 B size)
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Request Priority: Highest
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I know the PHP script executes, since I can have it do something else (like echo a string on the page) and that will run just fine. So the 'file_upload.php' function does run - I just can't figure out why I'm getting that error.

Thank you!

Comment: Your missing ; after the print_r() for one. Check your web server error log or add this to the top of you script to turn on error reporting to the browser. ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Hi Jason - that was an error on my part when writing the question. My code has it there - but good catch! I'll check it with the logs!

Comment: @JasonK The error: Warning: Undefined array key "file_upload". Is my form wrong?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. It runs for me. print_r($_FILES); to see what you have.

Comment: Still getting 
Warning: Undefined array key "file_upload"

Comment: Don't include the index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253303/discussion-between-thecrazyswede-and-jason-k).

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong at this point. If your code the same as you question. Did you change something without realizing. take a look at the dev tools. F12 network tab to see what is being sent. look at the web server error log for some other error.  dump the $_POST and $_FILES to see what they have. Are you running local or on a service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this one works for me..

```
    $targetDir = "your/folder/to/save/";
    $fileName = basename($_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]);
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath);
```